# c++ how to create an aggregate that store lambdas and can be passed to a function as designated initializers

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, aggregate-initialization

I'm trying to pass an aggregate that stores functions as designated initializers with no success.

This is what I tried:

```
    typedef struct Handlers
    {
        std::function<void()> func1 = nullptr;
        std::function<void()> func2 = nullptr;
        std::function<void()> func3 = nullptr;
        std::function<void()> func4 = nullptr; 
    } Handlers;

    class Person
    {
    public:
        Person(const char *name, 
               uint16_t age, 
               Handlers &&handlers);

        void doSomething();
    };
```

this is how i'm trying to pass the functions

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Person p1(
        "Guy",
        28,
        { 
          .func1 = []() {},
          .func2 = []() {},
          .func3 = []() {},
          .func4 = []() {}
        });
}
```

One of the error messages:

```
no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Handlers&&’
   35 |     Person(const char *name, uint16_t age, Handlers &&handlers);
```

Comment: `.set_connack_handler = ` ? -> `.func1 = `

Comment: I will edit. I changed the names for simplicity and forgot to change it too.

Comment: What version gcc u use? on gcc9.3 works fine https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GnlsDQ

Comment: @Arenoros compilation does. Linking does not. He's gonna get a linker error. Check the "compile to binary" and you get an error on godbolt. Because he haven't declared the constructor, and it can't be generated in this case by compiler.

Comment: Fine with clang/gcc/msvc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/iFmLQs).

Comment: @guy, nope, all works correctly https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/K8s9ki

Comment: @Arenoros because this isn't the code from OP, you implemented the constructor.

Comment: @vtronko: link error is unrelated to OP issue. OP has compile error.

Comment: @vtronko, just for example, obviously it's doesn't work without constructor implementation

Comment: Just for the record, the constructor is implemented in a cpp file + include. and there are include guard. but, I don't think it's related.

Comment: @Arenoros Thank you, I will check if it work on a new project.

Comment: Ok, no luck. if someone will successfully solve it, I will be happy to know how to make it work. or even know why does it happens. it seems like the argument type is not matching to the parameter type.